# Ordenar ArrayList de enteros en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un código que genera un Array de un tamaño aleatorio, y dentro del mismo se generarán números aleatorios. Todo bien hasta aquí.
Ahora, debo hacer un segundo Array a donde voy a mover los mismos valores, pero, ordenados según el siguiente criterio:

1. El primer elemento del Array1 será el primero del Array2.
2. El segundo elemento del Array2 será el último del Array1.
3. El tercer elemento del Array2 será el segundo del Array1.
4. El cuarto elemento del Array2 será el penúltimo del Array1.

Y así, sucesivamente hasta que no queden más elementos que ordenar.

Por ejemplo, tengo este Array1 que es de 9 elementos:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Y según los criterios que mencioné, mi Array2 debería quedar así:

```
{1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5}
```

Mi código está quedando de esta manera:

```
private static Random r = new Random();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = r.nextInt(6)+4;
    int nsquare = (n*n); //elevar al cuadrado el valor de n
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(nsquare);
    ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(nsquare); //Servirá como un array ordenado según criterios

    System.out.println("Tamaño de la lista: "+ nsquare +" elementos\n");
    for (int x = 0; x < nsquare; x++) {
        fillarray(array);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < nsquare; x++) {
        array2 = array; //Esto lo tengo únicamente para ver si imprimía el mismo array, fuera de eso, esta parte es innecesaria
    }
    printarray(array);
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    printarray(array2);       
    
}

//LLENAR ARRAY
public static void fillarray(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    int e = r.nextInt(9)+1;
    array.add(e);
}

//IMPRIMIR ARRAY
public static void printarray(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    int rowcont = 1; //contador de renglones--> ESTÉTICA
    for(int number : array)
    System.out.println(String.format("%2s", rowcont++) +" -->   ["+ String.format("%2s", number) +"]"); //String.format para darle formato y alinear los números; rowcont avanzará del 1 hasta el tamaño del arreglo
}
```

Lo único que me faltaría sería ordenar mi segundo Array de la forma que mencioné. No sé si debo estar eliminando el elemento del primer array y añadirlo al segundo y no vuelva a repetir. Espero puedan ayudarme, por favor.

Comment: Pero cual seria el problema?

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo ordenar los elementos de mi segundo array en base a los pasos que mencioné, para que quede como en el ejemplo? Debo aclarar que los elementos del array y del array2 deben ser los mismos, pero en el segundo, organizados.

Comment: Ese es tu ejercicio.. que intentaste?

Comment: Traté de hacer un método en el cual estaría una variable auxiliar que buscara el último elemento del primer array, lo eliminara de ese array y lo moviera al segundo, respetando el orden, pero simplemente no me sale.

Comment: Y porque eliminas del primer array? y no sale.. que sale? mostra lo que hiciste, explica que hace, mostra como sale.... asi podemos corregirte.. si no, es como hacer el ejercicio por vos...

Comment: @gbianchi, me puedes explicar el porqué del voto negativo que dieron a mi respuesta,

Comment: @gbianchi, después de haber sido aceptada por el usuario

Comment: @Japv desconozco, eso lo sabra quien te dio el voto negativo. Yo solo puedo especular que resolviste un ejercicio que no tenia ningun intento por resolverlo... La pregunta asi planteada es haganme el ejercicio.

Comment: @gbianchi, el usuario puso lo que intentó, si no hubiera puesto nada seria otra cosa(suponiendo que ese haya sido el motivo) a mi más bien me parece un voto de castigo porque a alguien le dio su gana, pero bueno...

Comment: @Japv yo no veo ningun intento en su codigo por resolver el punto que plantea. si lleno el array aleatoriamente, pero luego de eso no intento resolver el ejercicio y se lo hice saber ayer cuando le pregunte respecto a lo que habia intentado. Igual, sera un voto castigo, no lo se, si quien voto no dice nada imposible saberlo. No es algo que yo pueda resolver

Comment: @gbianchi, hice el intento, evitando ayudarme de las respuestas dadas, pero deseo sugerencias a mi código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int incremento = 2;
int indice = 0;
int a1 = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++)
{
   a1 = array1.get(i);
   array2.set(indice, a1);
   índice += incremento;

   if(indice >= array2.size())
   {
      índice = índice - 1;
      incremento = -2;
   }
}
```

Se declaran la variables:

**incremento**: guardará el valor que nos indicará cuanto incrementará la **variable indice**.

**indice**: guardará la posición en que se guardarán los elementos de **array1** en **array2**.

**a1**: guardará un valor del **array1**.

Se ejecuta un **ciclo for** que recorrerá todos los elementos de **array1** para irlos guardando en **array2**.

Resulta que en **array2** se irán guardando cada dos posiciones los elementos de **array1**, es decir el valor de **array2** en la posición **0** será el valor de **array1** en la posición **0**, el valor de **array2** en la posición **2** será el valor de **array1** en la posición **1**, el valor de **array2** en la posición **4** será el valor de **array1** en la posición **2**, de esta forma llenamos las posiciones pares de **array2**, faltarían las impares.

Cuando la **variable indice** tiene el mismo valor que el tamaño del arreglo entonces se le resta **1** a la **variable indice** y la **variable incremento** toma el valor **-2**, de esta forma se llenan las posiciones impares de **array2** con los otros elementos de **array1**.

Answer (score -2):

```
   int vectorOriginal[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
   int vectorSalida[] = new int[9]; 

   int inicio =0;
   int fin = 8;
   for(int i=0;i<vectorOriginal.length;i+=2){
       vectorSalida[i]=vectorOriginal[inicio];
       inicio +=1;
       try {
            vectorSalida[i+1]=vectorOriginal[fin];
            fin -=1;
       } catch (Exception e) {
       }
   }
```

¡Te ofrezco esta otra solución!

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, agrega una explicación del código por favor , revisa [answer], saludos.